# JavaScript Syntax issue to target the correct element

Tags: javascript

I have a JS function that replaces an element by another with FadeOut / FadeIn animation :

```
$('.avatar-name span').fadeOut("slow", function() {   /*fade out old file-name*/
    $('.avatar-name').append('<span>'+file.name+'</span>');   /*Add file-name*/
    $('.avatar-name span').hide().fadeIn("slow");
    $('.avatar-name span:first-child').remove();   /*remove old file-name now*/
});
```

It works great when the target element is the following :

```
<td class="avatar-name">
    <span><?php if(isset($acc_avatar)) echo $acc_avatar;?></span>
</td>
```

But when I have an input in the same `<td>` like this :

```
<td class="avatar-name">
    <input type="hidden" name="acc-avatar" id="acc-avatar" value="">
    <span><?php if(isset($acc_avatar)) echo $acc_avatar;?></span>
</td>
```

Then it messes up completly (element being multiplied instead of removed and other weird events).
Surely I am missing something but I can't put my finger on it. I'm looking for some help to adapt the JS for the `<td>` including the input.

Thank you for helping me out !

Comment: You might try adding a slash before the > of the input tag to close it:      <input type="hidden" name="acc-avatar" id="acc-avatar" value="" />. I'm not sure if that is what is causing your issue or not.

Comment: @DHP `<input>` tags are self-closing, they don't need the slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have an input before the span, the span is no longer the first child (the input is the first child, the span is the second child), so `span:first-child` doesn't match it. Use `:first` instead of `:first-child`.

```
$('.avatar-name span').fadeOut("slow", function() {   /*fade out old file-name*/
    $('.avatar-name').append('<span>'+file.name+'</span>');   /*Add file-name*/
    $('.avatar-name span').hide().fadeIn("slow");
    $('.avatar-name span:first').remove();   /*remove old file-name now*/
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation !

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet to assist.

Just fade out the span, remove old one, append new, fade in new.

You could also just change the text of the span with $('.avatar-name').text("newText");

```js
$('.avatar-name').fadeOut("slow", function() {   /*fade out old file-name*/
    $('.avatar-name span').remove();   /*remove old file-name now*/
    var newSpan = $('.avatar-name').append('<span>NEW SPAN</span>');   /*Add file-name*/
    newSpan.fadeIn("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>

  <tr>
  
<td class="avatar-name">
    <input type="hidden" name="acc-avatar" id="acc-avatar" value="Val">
    <span>Original span</span>
</td>
  </tr>
  
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I validated Barmar's answer since it directly fixes the error in my code and it may be useful if somebody does the same mistake as I did. However your solution involving `text("newText")` actually matches more what I was trying to do in the first place, so I will go with this :) Thanks for your help !

Comment: Also would you happen to know if the equivalent of `.text("newText")` exists for images ? For instance to replace `<img src="/avatar/image1.png" width="150" height="150"/>` by `<img src="/avatar/new-image.png" width="150" height="150"/>` ?

Comment: <img class="image1" src="/avatar/image1.png" width="150" height="150"/> you would use jquery $(".image1").attr("src", "/avatar/new-image.png");